# Various programs are crashing with an access violation (0xc000000d). What's wrong?

Tags: windows, crash

For a few months now, various unrelated programs have been periodically crashing on me. This seems to happen more often when a program has been open a while, versus just opening and closing it within a short timeframe. What's interesting is that all of the crashes have the same offset, specifically **0x77xx4b41**, which corresponds to where **ntdll.dll** is loaded.

A selection of programs where this occurs:

- Adobe Reader
- eM Client (a managed .NET 4 executable)
- iWrap.exe (the Intel PROset profile migrator thingy, it crashes when you hit cancel on the dialog to select a profile to import)
- Proxmon.exe and AccessEnum.exe (Sysinternals tools)
- windbg.exe
- ...and others.

My machine is Windows 10 32-bit with 4GB RAM, upgraded all the way from XP ("do a fresh install" is not an answer I will accept). There are no hardware problems that I know of, and memtest86/chkdsk/dism/sfc all come back clean. How do I find out what's causing this?

Comment: Test your RAM with Memtest86. You probably have a stick that is failing or a bad slot.

Comment: 0xc000000d = STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER - An invalid parameter was passed to a service or function.

Comment: Use [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) to analyze the crashes. This can find if the cause is a driver or a device. If you would like us to have a look, post some `.dmp` files, normally found in `c:\windows\minidump`. Have a look also in the Event Viewer for interesting errors.

Comment: Download [Procdump](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900) and run `procdump.exe -i` command to install it as _AeDebug postmortem debugger_. This will create a crash dump every time a program crash. By seeing the list of crashed program you provided, I can see you already have `windbg.exe`. Load the crash dump in it and run `!analyze -v` to analyze the crash dump. Or use **BlueScreenView**, as @harrymc suggested.

Comment: run sfc.exe and check you do not have a corrupted system file